# Is there a way to analyse a text file to check for this criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file, cpu-word

I need to create a program that analyses a passage of text from a file and then counts:

- How many words
- The average length of a word
- How many times each word occurs
- How many words start with each letter of the alphabet

So far I have managed to complete the first two bullet points (as seen below),

```
fileName = open(input('Please enter the full name of the file: '), 'r') 
    w = [len(word) for line in fileName for word in line.rstrip().split(" ")]
    total_w = len(w)
    avg_w = sum(w) / total_w
    
    
  print('The total number of words in this file is:', total_w)
  print('The average length of the words in this file is:', avg_w)
```

Comment: Hi Inaya, welcome to StackOverflow. So your question can have the most potential to be answered, please list a specific question you have in your post. What exactly are you stuck on? Right now, your question quite broad - too broad for a useful answer.

Comment: Also, just some very brief hints on the other bullet points: (1) Try breaking the file up by whitespace, filtering out punctuation, then counting each word. (3) Try using a [dictionary](https://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php) here and see what you can come up with. (4) Try combing the general approach used in (1) & (3), taking note of using dictionaries. These should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) makes this relatively straightforward. I use `re.findall(r'[\w]+', data)` to find words (where words are things with letters, underscore and numbers). Adjust as needed.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

fn = input('Please enter the full name of the file: ')
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    words = Counter(re.findall(r'[\w]+', f.read()))
    # use words = Counter(f.read().split()) if everything split by spaces
    # adjust regular expression depending on whether you want or don't want
    # stuff like numbers to be counted as "words"

print('Total number of words:', sum(words.values()))
# this is weighted by word occurrence, not sure whether this is correct
print('Average length of words:', 
      sum(len(w) * o for w, o in words.items()) / sum(words.values()))
print('Word occurrence:', words)
# this only shows letters that actually occur. If you need all letters of 
# the alphabet, you have to add the rest
print('Start letter occurrence', Counter(w[0] for w in words.elements()))
```